# Nginx rewrite sub page as main page (laravel)

Tags: nginx, php, rewrite

I have a page on my site: http://example.com/sub-page

I want that page to be seen when I visit: http://example.com/

The site is a dynamic php page (laravel site) which requires the following config in nginx:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```

I tried using `rewrite ^/$ /sub-page last;` in the above location block but it doesn't work as intended.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and most maintainable way is to change the page URLs in Laravel. Configuring hacks in nginx configuration to accomplish your goal will lead to many problems in the future.

Comment: its just to temporarily show the page as the main page on a separate domain to the main site. i was hoping there was a way to accomplish this without having to explicitly hardcode the domain in laravel. is there no way nginx can do this?

Comment: Then you should set up a reverse proxy from the other domain to the page in subdirectory.